# CountIF and AverageIF a column

Tags: vba, excel, countif

Hi All Excel/VBA experts,

Need your help on making a macro that counts the average count of a city from a column. Right below I have a macro that can count the number of a city from the given array.
Need to put the average count of the city next to the name. 
Thank you for the help.

```
Public Sub CountA()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastCell As String
Dim countRange As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet 'Change as appropriate

Set countRange = ws.Range(Cells(2, "V"), Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V"))

Debug.Print countRange.Address

Dim Cities()
Cities = Array("Auckland", "Brisbane", "Melbourne", "Seoul", "Tokyo", "Sydney", "Bratislava", "Bangalore", "Chennai", "Gurgaon", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata", "New Delhi", "Noida", "Mumbai", "London", "Munich", "Unterfohring", "Aachen", "Abidjan", "Abington", "Alpharetta", "Amstelveen", "Amsterdam", "Anaheim", "Aquascalientes", "Arlon", "Ashland", "Atlanta", "Aurora", "Austin", "Barcelona", "Basel", "Batavia", "Bay Village", "Belton", "Berkshire", "Berlin", "Birmingham", "Bogota", "Boise", "Boston", "Bramley", "Brandon", "Brecksville", "Brentwood", "Bridgetown", "Brussels", "Budapest", "Buffalo Grove", "Bury", "Cairo", "Callahan", "Calumet City", "Cape Town", "Capitola", "Cardiff", "Carmel", "Centennial", "Chanhassen", "Charlotte", "Cheltenham", "Cincinnati", "Clearwater", "Clemson", "Cleveland", "Cohoes", "Columbia", "Columbus", "Conifer", "Cookeville", "Copenhagen", "Coral Gables", "Croydon", "Culver City", "Cumming", "Cutchogue", "Dallas", "Dallas Park", "Darmstadt", "Double Oak", "Dublin")

Dim city As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim startRange As Range
Set startRange = ws.Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V").Offset(2, 0)

counter = 2

For city = LBound(Cities) To UBound(Cities)
    Debug.Print Cities(x)
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city)) > 0 Then
    startRange.Offset(counter, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city))
    startRange.Offset(counter, 1) = Cities(city)
     counter = counter + 1

  End If

Next city


End Sub
```

Tried this:

```
For city = LBound(Cities) To UBound(Cities) 
    Debug.Print Cities(x) 
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(countRange, Cities(city)) > 0 Then 
        startRange.Offset(counter, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(countRange, Cities(city)) 
        startRange.Offset(counter, 1) = Cities(city)
```

Currently my code can CountIf the City highlighted in BLUE and shows the result below it highlighted in RED and Highlighted in Yellow. My objective is to add another data which is the percentage of the city highlighted in Green. I can do that manually by doing fo rexample *=COUNTIF(V2:V25,"Bratislava")/COUNTA(V2:V5)* . But as you could see on my arrays I need to type everything manually per city. Thank you for the expert help.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you know you need to use AVERAGEIF() here - did you try that?  It's quite similar to your existing code...

Comment: I did change countif to averageif but giving me the run time error 1004: Unable to get the averageif property if the worksheefFunction class.

Comment: It's usually best to post the code that's failing, and include the error message

Comment: For city = LBound(Cities) To UBound(Cities)
        Debug.Print Cities(x)
      If Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(countRange, Cities(city)) > 0 Then
        startRange.Offset(counter, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(countRange, Cities(city))
        startRange.Offset(counter, 1) = Cities(city)


This is the code that is failing(highlighted in yellow). The error message is: Run time error 1004. Unable to get the averageif property if the worksheefFunction class.

Comment: Did you notice that AverageIf takes one more argument than Countif?  You need to tell it where to take the average from.  So for example `Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(countRange, Cities(city), countRange.Offset(0,1))` if the values you want to average are in the column to the right of the City names.

Comment: @TimWilliams `For city = LBound(Cities) To UBound(Cities)
    Debug.Print Cities(X)
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(countRange, Cities(city), countRange.Offset(0, 1)) > 0 Then
    startRange.Offset(counter, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(countRange, Cities(city), countRange.Offset(0, 1))
    startRange.Offset(counter, 1) = Cities(city)` but still not working. he error message is: Run time error 1004. Unable to get the averageif property if the worksheefFunction class. Please help.

Comment: @Jonathan: definitely note Tim's comment in the code about loading cities names from a worksheet range. If i remember correctly from your prior post, there are a lot of cities to enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a couple of lines.

Get the total number of cities:

```
Dim citiesCount As Long
citiesCount = countRange.Rows.Count
```

Write out the proportion of the total number of cities of each city:

```
startRange.Offset(counter, -1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city)) / citiesCount
```

I would highly recommend you use Tim's suggestion of reading in the cities from a worksheet rather than typing them all in.

I would also recommend error handling in case nothing is present in column V.

With the additional lines you get:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CountA()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastCell As String
Dim countRange As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet 'Change as appropriate

Set countRange = ws.Range(Cells(2, "V"), Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V"))

Dim Cities()
Cities = Array("Auckland", "Brisbane", "Melbourne", "Seoul", "Tokyo", "Sydney", "Bratislava", "Bangalore", "Chennai", "Gurgaon", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata", "New Delhi", "Noida", "Mumbai", "London", "Munich", "Unterfohring", "Aachen", "Abidjan", "Abington", "Alpharetta", "Amstelveen", "Amsterdam", "Anaheim", "Aquascalientes", "Arlon", "Ashland", "Atlanta", "Aurora", "Austin", "Barcelona", "Basel", "Batavia", "Bay Village", "Belton", "Berkshire", "Berlin", "Birmingham", "Bogota", "Boise", "Boston", "Bramley", "Brandon", "Brecksville", "Brentwood", "Bridgetown", "Brussels", "Budapest", "Buffalo Grove", "Bury", "Cairo", "Callahan", "Calumet City", "Cape Town", "Capitola", "Cardiff", "Carmel", "Centennial", "Chanhassen", "Charlotte", "Cheltenham", "Cincinnati", "Clearwater", "Clemson", "Cleveland", "Cohoes", "Columbia", "Columbus", "Conifer", "Cookeville", "Copenhagen", "Coral Gables", "Croydon", "Culver City", "Cumming", "Cutchogue", "Dallas", "Dallas Park", "Darmstadt", "Double Oak", "Dublin")

Dim city As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim startRange As Range

Set startRange = ws.Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V").Offset(2, 0)

counter = 2

Dim citiesCount As Long
citiesCount = countRange.Rows.Count 'new line to hold total number of cities

For city = LBound(Cities) To UBound(Cities)

  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city)) > 0 Then
    startRange.Offset(counter, -1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city)) / citiesCount 'new line to calculate proportion of total
    startRange.Offset(counter, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city))
    startRange.Offset(counter, 1) = Cities(city)
     counter = counter + 1

  End If

Next city

End Sub
```

Here is a version 2 reading the list of cities from a worksheet called CitiesList, ensuring you are in right sheets and some error handling for empty count range.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CountA()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
  ' Dim lastCell As String ''not used
    Dim countRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")             'Change as appropriate

    Set countRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "V"), ws.Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V"))

    Dim Cities()
    Cities = GetCities                           'Call function to populate array with cities from worksheet

    Dim city As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim startRange As Range

    On Error Resume Next 'Error handling for range being empty. Might not be the best error handling.
    Set startRange = ws.Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V").Offset(2, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If startRange Is Nothing Then
       Exit Sub
    Else
       Resume
    End If

    counter = 2

    Dim citiesCount As Long
    citiesCount = countRange.Rows.Count

    With ws                                      'make sure in right sheet

        For city = LBound(Cities, 1) To UBound(Cities, 1)

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city, 1)) > 0 Then
                startRange.Offset(counter, -1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city, 1)) / citiesCount
                startRange.Offset(counter, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city, 1))
                startRange.Offset(counter, 1) = Cities(city, 1)
                counter = counter + 1

            End If

        Next city

    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetCities() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CitiesList")
    GetCities = ws.Range("B2", ws.Range("B2").End(xlDown)) ' Amend as appropriate

End Function
```

Comment: Great it works!! Thank you! I am using the 1st version.

Comment: Sorry for being pain in the a$$, if a 1 or 2 rows out of 80 rows in column V is empty, how would I rename that to string?

Comment: Do you mean if one/ two city names are missing from the range you would like to put something like "Not specified" ?

Comment: Have you changed the formula?   This line Set countRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "V"), ws.Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V")) means that your range to count over stops at the first blank so there wouldn't be any missing cities in the selected range. If you defined the range in a different way e.g.   Set countRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "V"), ws.Cells(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row, "V")) then you might. The second version would find the last used cell in the column V and would include blank cells.

Comment: No I didn't change it and the code works perfectly. Since I am running the macro for a daily exported report, in some occasion a cell out of 90 cells in column V is empty. I want to add a value to that cell. For example "Not specified". So that the row will also be calculated on the total and percentage.

Comment: Are you actually always handling a set range then? That being the 90 rows Range("V2:V91") ?

Comment: You will need to change how you are setting the countRange as it will stop at the first blank. You can use the alternative i suggested above. After you Set the countRange add the following line: 
countRange.Replace What:="", Replacement:="Not Specified", LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows

Comment: The range is not fix. It differs everyday. The code does not actually stop at any blank cell it just does not count it. It does a great job ignoring it.

Comment: Thank you QHarr!  how will I able to auto sum the results from this line `startRange.Offset(counter, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(countRange, Cities(city))`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Where do you want to put headers? The offset line means that you will always have the cities counts starting at 2 rows below the end row. If data ended at "V4" the counts would start at "V6" etc. You could place a header in between with startRange.Offset(1, 0)  = "header" or some such but i am not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: From the original question above highlighted in blue, those are the results from the countif function. how would i sum the results.

Comment: The sum by city is shown in where your red box is. The overall sum is in the variable citiesCount which is citiesCount = countRange.Rows.Count

Comment: oh yes in red sorry. how would i display that at the bottom of the highlighted in red?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159074/discussion-between-qharr-and-jonathan).

Answer (score 0):

Compiled but not tested:

```
Public Sub CountA()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastCell As String
    Dim countRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet 'Change as appropriate

    Set countRange = ws.Range(Cells(2, "V"), Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V"))

    Debug.Print countRange.Address

    Dim Cities()
    '<TW> you should really load these from a worksheet....
    Cities = Array("Auckland", "Brisbane", "Melbourne", "Seoul", "Tokyo", "Sydney", _
                    "Bratislava", "Bangalore", "Chennai", "Gurgaon", "Hyderabad")

    Dim city As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim startRange As Range
    Dim r As Variant
    Set startRange = ws.Cells(ws.Range("V2").End(xlDown).Row, "V").Offset(2, 0)

    counter = 2

    For city = LBound(Cities) To UBound(Cities)

        Debug.Print Cities(city)

        'assuming the values to be averaged are in the column to the right of the city names
        '   adjust as required...
        r = Application.AverageIf(countRange, Cities(city), countRange.Offset(0, 1))

        startRange.Offset(counter, 0).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(r, Cities(city))
        counter = counter + 1

     Next city

End Sub
```

Comment: The code runs but gives me _#DIV/0!_ as a result next to the City name.

Comment: In which column are the values you want to average for each city?

Comment: Starting from V2 to the last cell that has value(City). Which is the same from my original CountIf macro posted above.

Comment: "Need to put the average count of the city next to the name" - what *exactly* are you trying to do here?  Average of what?  I was assuming there was another column with numeric data you needed to average.  If that's not the case then how are you getting an average?

Comment: I have edited my question above for clarification. Thank you.